# find number of string sequence in a string in java

Tags: java, string

```
      class Plan{ 
    String str;
    String findstring;
      public void countsubString(String str,String findString){
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
    if(str.contains(findString)){ 
        count++;
     }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
 }   
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{  
     Plan b=new Plan(); 
     System.out.println("Enter the string..");
     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str=br.readLine();
      BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String findstring=br1.readLine();
      b.countsubString(str, findstring);
}    
}
```

I have a string cow wow wow cow cow wow wow ,i have to find how many times cow is present?Means give a sequence of string and find a substring how many time it present in that string?

Comment: `for(int i=0;i< ;i++)` ?

Comment: Also what's the problem? Please specify.

Comment: indentation is important! please strive to keep code lined up properly

Comment: I just want to travel from start to end if i am going to give lengh(),then it will count the string lengh??So is there any other way to find the sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contains` is not right method. Use `equals` like below

```
public void countsubString(String str,String findString){
    int count=0;
    String strArr[]=str.split(" +");
    for(String str: strArr){
    if(str.equals(findString)){ 
        count++;
     }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the following code:

```
for(int i=0;i< ;i++){
if(str.contains(findString)){ 
    count++;
 }
}
```

use the following:

```
int lastIndex = 0;
while(lastIndex != -1){

       lastIndex = str.indexOf(findString,lastIndex);

       if( lastIndex != -1){
             count ++;
             lastIndex+=findString.length();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use regex with group capture. More efficient,readable and lesser code.

```
        String str = "cow wow wow cow cow wow wow";
        Matcher cowMatcher = Pattern.compile("(.*?cow)")
                .matcher(
                    str);
        int count=0;

        while (cowMatcher.find()) {
        ++count;
    }
```

Comment: This can be further simplified by using `recipientAttrMatcher.groupCount()`.

Comment: Here, count=0, have you tested it?

Comment: @phlogratos i tried   count=cowMatcher.groupCount(); but it return 1. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I got this wrong. `groupCount` doesn't count the groups in the result, but in the regular expression. So this method can't be used here.